# How to make WebRTC work on 3G networks using the STUN and TURN?

Tags: webrtc

Does not work the connection between clients provided that one client uses the 3G network.

The configuration of server uses STUN and TURN.

The problem starts at the stage ICE. In console of Firefox browser the message: "ICE failed. Your TURN server appears to be broken."

The logs of WebRTC shows the next (shorted):
"
(stun/INFO) TURN Timed out
(turn/WARNING) mode 20
(turn/WARNING) nr_turn_client_error_cb
(turn/WARNING) failed
(turn/INFO) cancelling
(turn/WARNING) nr_turn_allocated_cb called with state 4
(turn/WARNING) nr_turn_allocated_cb failed
(stun/INFO) Timed out
(ice/INFO)  All pairs are failed, and grace period has elapsed. Marking component as failed.
"

Do you know the standard solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in WebRTC these days, so I don't know the exact cause, but I would like to help you.

When I look at this "error message", it appears that you can't connect to the TURN server when you are connected to a 3G network.

---

1) Check if there is a TURN server on a private network.

2) Make sure that the ISP (Internet service provider) supplying your 3G network is blocking access to this TURN server.

3) Or, make sure that the firewall on the TURN server only allows only specific IP connections.

4) Other...

---

Network problems are so diverse that you have to check each one to find out the exact cause.

Thank you.